# Same result is not achieved with while-loop and for-loop

Tags: php

```html
With for loop 
$for = array (
  array(1, "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", 12209, "Germany"),
  array(2, "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "Ana Trujillo", "Avda. de la Constitución 2222", "México D.F.", 5021, "Mexico"),
);




for($x = 0; $x < 2; $x ++) {

    for($col = 0; $col < 7; $col ++){

        echo $for[$x][$col] . "</br>";
    }
}

with while loop 
$while = array (
  array(1, "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", 12209, "Germany"),
  array(2, "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "Ana Trujillo", "Avda. de la Constitución 2222", "México D.F.", 5021, "Mexico"),
);


$x = 0;

while ($x <= 1) {

    $x ++;

    $col = 0;

    while ($col <= 6) {

        echo $while[$x][$col] . "</br>";

        $col++;
    }
}
```

I do like to get the same result with while-loop as I get with for loop, but when I do it with a while loop, then it gives me for the first time the second row result, and after the second result give me an error as i have shown below.

2
Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados
Ana Trujillo
Avda. de la Constitución 2222
México D.F.
5021
Mexico

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\array.php on line 39

Comment: seems like you code has a mistake: where do you define the $y variable?

Comment: the best way to avoid such a mistakes is always giving a meaningful name to every single variable, even to iterations counters

Comment: sir i have edit it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop, you are incrementing the `$x` before you process it's value, so you're missing the iteration that would be `$x=0`. Also, rather than hard code your max numbers, use the length of the array you're iterating with `count($array)`. See testable link at the bottom

```
<?php

$for = array (
  array(1, "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", 12209, "Germany"),
  array(2, "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "Ana Trujillo", "Avda. de la Constitución 2222", "México D.F.", 5021, "Mexico"),
);
for($x = 0; $x < count($for); $x ++) {
    for($col = 0; $col < count($for[$x]); $col ++){
        echo $for[$x][$col] . "\n";
    }
}
$while = array (
  array(1, "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", 12209, "Germany"),
  array(2, "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "Ana Trujillo", "Avda. de la Constitución 2222", "México D.F.", 5021, "Mexico"),
);    
$x = 0;
while ($x < count($while)) {
    $col = 0;
    while ($col < count($while[$x])) {
        echo $while[$x][$col] . "\n";
        $col++;
    }
    $x ++;
}
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/c32uLNFCqfrUtaeL

Also note that you can use foreach, which makes things a little tidier

```
foreach($while as $a) foreach($a as $item) echo $item . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you,s dear it work now actually i was dealing with the database and I have used the mysqli_fetch_all() function then it return the multidimensional array for that purpose I did this